# How do I get block details in a Pyro CMS twig file?

Tags: laravel, content-management-system, pyrocms, pyro

The url contains a block id, such as this domain/playlist/PLQB0d-uOBCP2vyGFcj3nw252x9CtupDH1/{blockid}. How do I get all of the information from the block id into the twig file?

Comment: Try to get it from route

Comment: Typically blocks are not selected like this but instead iterated over like a stack of content for example. 

It sounds like you want a separate stream/table with this data. Then you can `find($id)` it using the last segment or something similar within your template.